# How to find the transfer function of a frequency counter?

Tags: control-system, counter, transfer-function, matlab, frequency-measurement

I am designing a mathematical model for my control systems project and in that there is this block which measures the frequency of the wave.
For the practical application I fed this wave into a micro controller and then wrote an algorithm which takes in samples of the wave at a fixed rate and finds out the minimas and maximas and using them finds out the frequency.
But I dont understand how to proceed doing it mathematically so that I create a block of this counter whose input will be the wave and output will be the frequency.
Any idea on how to proceed with this?

Comment: You wrote an algorithm that presumably does what you want, yes? Nobody on stack exchange has access to that algorithm, yes? So far, you hold all the aces!

Comment: Well the code was written in the arduino programming language  
but if you do want more information on how the algorithm is working, I can surely provide you with that???

Comment: You understand, I hope, that the sample frequency must be  higher than the highest component frequency of the signal? If you're depending on Nyquist rates you _must_ band-limit the signal, which may well require a rather sophisticated filter.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a frequency counter integrates the frequency over the gate period and then holds it until the next sample is available.

A crude model (perhaps suitable for loop stability analysis) would be a dead time of half the gate period (accurate to the extent the frequency is changing linearly and assuming the measurements are continuous), but you could model it more exactly if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Spehro's answer - "integrator divided by the gate period (time or samples)" is simply an average - a leaky integrator. So you can use (with the appropriate scaling) a boxcar filter to model your frequency counter. The transfer function is

$$\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{z^N+z^{N-1}+...1}{Nz^N}$$